# Is there a way to identify CLR event instances in F#?

Tags: f#

When I'm working in F# Interactive, I often want to make changes to an event handler. Simply calling the Subscribe or Add or AddHandler functions on an event causes the old event to continue being called, which is rarely the intention.

One solution is to use the IDisposable that it returns, but that requires tracking the IDisposables in your own code, which is cumbersome for exploratory tasks.

I've tried making a `Dictionary<IEvent,IDisposable>` to call Dispose() when the same event is subscribed to again:

```
let events = Dictionary<obj, IDisposable>()
let subonce (e:IEvent<'h,'e>) (handler: 'e -> unit) =
    if events.ContainsKey e then
        events.[e].Dispose()
        events.Remove e |> ignore
    let d = e.Subscribe handler
    events.Add (e,d) |> ignore

let w = Window()
w.Show()

//Running this line in FSI a second time onward should Dispose() the previous subscription
subonce w.MouseUp (fun e -> printfn "%A" <| e.GetPosition(w))
```

Unfortunately, as it turns out, F# generates a new IEvent instance, so naively using `=` or `obj.Equals` doesn't cut it.

```
> w.MouseUp;;
val it : IEvent<Input.MouseButtonEventHandler,Input.MouseButtonEventArgs> =
  <published event> {addHandler = <fun:it@5-70>;
                     createHandler = <fun:it@5-72>;
                     removeHandler = <fun:it@5-71>;}

> w.MouseUp;;
val it : IEvent<Input.MouseButtonEventHandler,Input.MouseButtonEventArgs> =
  <published event> {addHandler = <fun:it@6-74>;   //note that these functions are of a different anonymous instance
                     createHandler = <fun:it@6-76>;
                     removeHandler = <fun:it@6-75>;}
```

Are there any properties or fields I can find within an IEvent that would identify it against other instances of the owner and against different events in that owner?

Comment: This is a very good question. I did some experimentation, but I cannot find a way to do this via a simple `subonce` function - I guess you'll need to provide the function with more information such as some string to be used as the key...

Comment: @TomasPetricek Not an answer to this question strictly speaking, but I ended up writing a function `IEvent<'h,'e> -> Handler` where Handler is just `type Handler<'e> = { mutable h : 'e -> unit }`. Then right after I define `w`, I can call `let wmouseup = onehandler w.MouseUp`, and then from then on, to change the handler, I do `wmouseup.h <- fun e -> ...`. `onehandler` is also trivial: `let onehandler (e:IEvent<'h,'e>) = let h = { h = fun _ -> () } in e.Subscribe(fun e -> h.h e) |> ignore; h`

Comment: That looks like something I would probably ended up doing! Can you post this as an answer to your question? I think it's the best option there is.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Done.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to the question, but I can't think of many other scenarios in which you'd need to identify an event instance, so maybe this is good enough:

```
type OneHandler<'e> = { mutable h : 'e -> unit }
let onehandler (e:IEvent<'h,'e>) =
    let h = { h = fun _ -> () }
    e.Subscribe(fun e -> h.h e) |> ignore
    h

let w = Window()
let wmouseup = onehandler w.MouseUp

wmouseup.h <- (fun e -> printfn "%A" <| e.GetPosition(w))
```

This way, by evaluating just the assignment to `wmouseup.h`, we can change the event handler without having to restart the `w` or juggle `IDisposable` or `Handler` objects.